# Zombienet: how to test custom parachain collator - block height(producing blocks) test

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, docker, zombienet

previously I could run my tests including colander parachain with polkadot:v0.9.18 or polkadot-debug...
my network definition file:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"
  args = ["--parachain-id 2000"]

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

Now when I changed that colander image to my own parachain image:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "gcr.io/p-network-202104/collator:v4"
  command = "target/release/parachain-collator"

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

And my tests:

```
Description: Small Network test
Network: ./z05-small-network.toml
Creds: config

# to run this file: ./zombienet-linux -p kubernetes test zombienet/z05-small-network.feature

# well know functions
alice: is up
bob: is up
alice: parachain 2000 is registered within 225 seconds

# logs
bob: log line matches glob "*rted #1*" within 10 seconds
bob: log line matches "Imported #[0-9]+" within 10 seconds
bob: log line matches "Imported new block." within 10 seconds

alice: parachain 2000 block height is at least 6 within 150 seconds

# Tracing
# alice: trace with traceID 94c1501a78a0d83c498cc92deec264d9 contains ["answer-chunk-request", "answer-chunk-request"]

# metrics
alice: reports node_roles is 4
alice: reports sub_libp2p_is_major_syncing is 0

# system events
bob: system event contains "A candidate was included" within 20 seconds
alice: system event matches glob "*was backed*" within 10 seconds
```

Then I got this command output:

```
  small network( Small Network test )
runningNetworkSpecPath undefined
     Launching network... this can take a while.

     Using provider: kubernetes

     Launching network under namespace: zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034
         Using temporary directory: /tmp/zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034_-144848-V9hN482nVZ36

    launching temp pod with image docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18
         with command: bash -c polkadot build-spec --chain rococo-local --disable-default-bootnode > /cfg/rococo-local-plain.json && until [ -f /tmp/finished.txt ]; do echo waiting for copy files to finish; sleep 1; done; echo copy files has finished
        temp pod is ready!

         Starting with a fresh authority set...
               Added Genesis Authority alice - 5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY
               Added Genesis Authority bob - 5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc

    launching temp-collator pod with image gcr.io/p-network/collator:latest
         with command: bash -c target/release/parachain-collator export-genesis-state > /cfg/genesis-state && target/release/parachain-collator export-genesis-wasm > /cfg/genesis-wasm && until [ -f /tmp/finished.txt ]; do echo waiting for copy files to finish; sleep 1; done; echo copy files has finished
        temp-collator pod is ready!

          ✓ Added Genesis Parachain 2000

    launching temp-1 pod with image docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18
         with command: bash -c polkadot build-spec --chain /cfg/rococo-local-plain.json --disable-default-bootnode  --raw > /cfg/rococo-local-raw.json && until [ -f /tmp/finished.txt ]; do echo waiting for copy files to finish; sleep 1; done; echo copy files has finished
uploading to fileserver: /tmp/zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034_-144848-V9hN482nVZ36/rococo-local-plain.json as:83f26480055f9cab6e46b477b9e66db48dc0e892d950ed0df817e05aefd69d9e
        temp-1 pod is ready!

         Chain name: Rococo Local Testnet

         ⚙ Clear Boot Nodes

    launching alice pod with image docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18
         with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh polkadot --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name alice --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external -lparachain=debug --no-mdns --node-key 2bd806c97f0e00af1a1fc3328fa763a9269723c8db8fac4f93af71db186d6e90 --no-telemetry --prometheus-external --jaeger-agent localhost:6831 --validator --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
uploading to fileserver: /tmp/zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034_-144848-V9hN482nVZ36/rococo-local.json as:c0730c2292ead75d4240c7c7623db1c40082c97ff4960ae8b0974597fc5c3498
uploading to fileserver: /tmp/zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034_-144848-V9hN482nVZ36/zombie-wrapper.sh as:640715d32ec3b23a0330febe7af0b9f37a6ffc8675cf88ecfdee1fa5b2b59b09
        alice pod is ready!
    alice running

         You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 

             kubectl logs -f alice -c alice -n zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034

         ⚙ Added Boot Nodes:  /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm

    launching bob pod with image docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18
         with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh polkadot --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name bob --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external -lparachain=debug --no-mdns --node-key 81b637d8fcd2c6da6359e6963113a1170de795e4b725b84d1e0b4cfd9ec58ce9 --no-telemetry --prometheus-external --jaeger-agent localhost:6831 --validator --bootnodes /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
        bob pod is ready!
    bob running

         You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 

             kubectl logs -f bob -c bob -n zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034
     All relay chain nodes spawned...

    launching collator01 pod with image gcr.io/p-network/collator:latest
         with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh target/release/parachain-collator --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name collator01 --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external --parachain-id 2000 --chain res/dev/rococo-custom-2-raw.json --no-mdns --node-key 5e123980fad4770d9ab5b7df7bbee8499943822a8555d11995e8203210065342 --no-telemetry --validator --bootnodes /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
        collator01 pod is ready!
    collator01 running

         You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 

             kubectl logs -f collator01 -c collator01 -n zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034

     Warn: Tracing collator service doesn't exist

-----------------------------------------


     Network launched 

         In namespace zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034 with kubernetes provider


         Node name: alice

         Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42683#/explorer

         Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:43531/metrics

---



         Node name: bob

         Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46627#/explorer

         Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:41273/metrics

---




     Parachain ID: 2000


         Node name: collator01

         Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46135#/explorer

         Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:41621/metrics

---

    ✔ alice: is up (66ms)
    ✔ bob: is up
2022-05-13 15:22:39        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead
    ✔ alice: parachain 2000 is registered within 225 seconds (2734ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches glob "*rted #1*" within 10 seconds (76ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches "Imported #[0-9]+" within 10 seconds (60ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches "Imported new block." within 10 seconds (61ms)

     Error:  
         Timeout(150), "getting desired parachain block height 6 within 150 secs".

    1) alice: parachain 2000 block height is at least 6 within 150 seconds
    ✔ alice: reports node_roles is 4
    ✔ alice: reports sub_libp2p_is_major_syncing is 0
2022-05-13 15:25:11        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead
    2) bob: system event contains "A candidate was included" within 20 seconds
2022-05-13 15:25:32        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead
    3) alice: system event matches glob "*was backed*" within 10 seconds

     Node's logs are available in /tmp/zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034_-144848-V9hN482nVZ36/logs

     Deleting network
2022-05-13 15:25:42        RPC-CORE: health(): Health:: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:42683: 1000:: Normal connection closure
2022-05-13 15:25:49        RPC-CORE: health(): Health:: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:42683: 1006:: Connection dropped by remote peer.
2022-05-13 15:25:50        RPC-CORE: getStorage(key: StorageKey, at?: BlockHash): StorageData:: WebSocket is not connected
child process exited
```

From above you can see the

- relaychain alice node test: ok
- relaychain bob node test: ok
- parachain 2000 is registered: ok
- 3 log tests: ok
- parachain 2000 block height test: failed!!?? Why did that fail?

When I was using `docker.io/paritypr/colander:master`, the block height test was successful...

Especially when I checked the collator logs via
`kubectl logs -f collator01 -c collator01 -n zombie-8a529a22b7767d93655b4bb89b74e034`
I got:

```
+ export PATH=/cfg:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ PATH=/cfg:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ pipe=/tmp/zombiepipe
+ trap 'rm -f /tmp/zombiepipe' EXIT
+ [[ ! -p /tmp/zombiepipe ]]
+ mkfifo /tmp/zombiepipe
+ child_pid=
+ CMD=($@)
+ child_pid=8
+ ls /proc/8
+ target/release/parachain-collator --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name collator01 --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external --parachain-id 2000 --no-mdns --node-key 5e123980fad4770d9ab5b7df7bbee8499943822a8555d11995e8203210065342 --no-telemetry --validator --bootnodes /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
+ read line
Error: Input("Error parsing spec file: missing field `relay_chain` at line 155 column 1")
```

Also the Polkadot.js link did not work as well
`Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46135#/explorer`

What is wrong?

My repo's docker-compose file:

```
  collator:
    container_name: collator
    image: pnetwork/collator
    ports:
      - "30343:30343"
      - "40333:40333"
      - "6969:6969"
      - "8844:8844"
      - "9977:9977"
    command: bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/parachain-collator --alice --collator --force-authoring --chain rococo-local --unsafe-ws-external --parachain-id 2000 --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe --base-path /tmp/parachain/alice --port 40333 --ws-port 8844 --rpc-port 6969 --rpc-cors all -- --execution wasm --chain res/dev/rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30343 --ws-port 9977 > collator.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"
    depends_on:
      - charlie-relay
  alice-relay:
    container_name: alice-relay
    image: pnetwork/relay
    ports:
      - "30333:30333"
      - "9944:9944"
    command: bash -c "apt-get install -y wget; nohup ./target/release/polkadot --alice --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/alice --chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-external --allow-private-ipv4 --discover-local --rpc-methods Unsafe > alice.out 2>&1; tail -f /dev/null"
```

My Dockerfile.base:

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt update && apt install -y git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev procps vim make wget build-essential
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf >> install-rust.sh
RUN chmod u+x install-rust.sh
RUN ./install-rust.sh -y
RUN PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/env
SHELL ["bash", "-lc"]
RUN rustup update
RUN rustup update nightly
RUN rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly

CMD [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/p-network-202104/rust as builder
ARG PROFILE=release
WORKDIR /builds/collator

COPY . .

RUN . $HOME/.cargo/env && cargo build --${PROFILE}

EXPOSE 40333-40335 8844-8848 6965-6969 30343-30345 9977-9979 30333 9933 9944

# TODO: Make this run the CMD used in the docker-compose-collator.yaml
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Is there any argument missing in my Zombienet network definition file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the correct Dockerfile and Zombienet network definition file at [Zombienet: Substrate-Parachain-Template ... How to write the Dockerfile?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/zombienet-substrate-parachain-template-how-to-write-the-dockerfile)

Answer (score 2):

looks like your parachain collator is based on cumulus (and not on one of the testnet like adder-collator), in that case you need to use the flag `cumulus_based` in the parachain definition.

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "gcr.io/p-network/collator:latest"
  command = "target/release/parachain-collator"
  args = ["--parachain-id 2000"]

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Russo, how you create your image? Can you share the Dockerfile and some logs from the collator?

Comment: Hi @Russo, can you update your Dockerfile to expose the default ports `30333 9933 9944`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Russo, is this the error `Error: Input("Error parsing spec file: missing field `relay_chain` at line 155 column 1")`, in this case looks like the chain-spec is wrong. Are the image public for try to reproduce?

Comment: Hi @Russo, but the output of zombienet show any error?
Thanks!

Comment: no error at all. Only my block height test failed, and the collator URL did not work as described above. That's all. any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Russo are you still using this line in your Dockerfile `CMD tail -f /dev/null` ? Can you post again your updated Dockerfile?

Comment: I have made a better question with Parachain-template: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/zombienet-substrate-parachain-template-block-heightblock-producing-test-f