# Zombienet: Substrate-Parachain-Template ... How to write the Dockerfile?

Tags: parachain, substrate-node-template, parachain-collator, docker, zombienet

This question follows those questions below:

Q1 [Zombienet: how to test custom parachain collator - block height(producing blocks) test](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/zombienet-how-to-test-custom-parachain-collator-block-heightproducing-blocks/2583)

Q2 [Zombienet: Substrate-Parachain-Template ... block height(block producing) test failed](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/zombienet-substrate-parachain-template-block-heightblock-producing-test-f)

Regarding this Docker template: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/scripts/ci/dockerfiles/collator_injected.Dockerfile, I got this answer from Q2 is "yes you can that one and add the build phase to inject then the binary."

That Dockerfile for making adder-collator image:

```
# this file copies from scripts/ci/dockerfiles/Dockerfile and changes only the binary name
FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04

# metadata
ARG VCS_REF
ARG BUILD_DATE
ARG IMAGE_NAME

LABEL io.parity.image.authors="devops-team@parity.io" \
    io.parity.image.vendor="Parity Technologies" \
    io.parity.image.title="${IMAGE_NAME}" \
    io.parity.image.description="Injected adder-collator Docker image" \
    io.parity.image.source="https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/${VCS_REF}/scripts/ci/dockerfiles/collator_injected.Dockerfile" \
    io.parity.image.revision="${VCS_REF}" \
    io.parity.image.created="${BUILD_DATE}" \
    io.parity.image.documentation="https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/"

# show backtraces
ENV RUST_BACKTRACE 1

# install tools and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        libssl1.1 \
        ca-certificates && \
# apt cleanup
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f -not -name lock -delete; \
# add user and link ~/.local/share/adder-collator to /data
    useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /adder-collator adder-collator && \
    mkdir -p /data /adder-collator/.local/share && \
    chown -R adder-collator:adder-collator /data && \
    ln -s /data /adder-collator/.local/share/polkadot

# add adder-collator binary to docker image
COPY ./adder-collator /usr/local/bin
COPY ./undying-collator /usr/local/bin

USER adder-collator

# check if executable works in this container
RUN /usr/local/bin/adder-collator --version
RUN /usr/local/bin/undying-collator --version

EXPOSE 30333 9933 9944
VOLUME ["/adder-collator"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/adder-collator"]
```

Then I used that to make my parachain collator image:

```
FROM gcr.io/p-network-202104/collator:c1 AS builder
# This c1 image has all the substrate-parachain-template code compiled

FROM debian@sha256:6ef4731388c03b38e58ea77aef9396c216095e1843742fc7cf5038901cc1f081
#FROM debian:stretch-slim
#buster-slim

COPY --from=builder ./builds/collator/target/release/parachain-collator /usr/local/bin

# show backtraces
ENV RUST_BACKTRACE 1

# install tools and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
  libssl1.1 \
  ca-certificates && \
  # apt cleanup
  apt-get autoremove -y && \
  apt-get clean && \
  find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f -not -name lock -delete; \
  # add user and link ~/.local/share/adder-collator to /data
  useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /adder-collator adder-collator && \
  mkdir -p /data /adder-collator/.local/share && \
  chown -R adder-collator:adder-collator /data && \
  ln -s /data /adder-collator/.local/share/polkadot

# adder-collator and undying-collator are not found. do I need them?
#COPY ./adder-collator /usr/local/bin
#COPY ./undying-collator /usr/local/bin

USER adder-collator

# adder-collator and undying-collator are not found
#RUN /usr/local/bin/adder-collator --version
#RUN /usr/local/bin/undying-collator --version

# adding code for new parachain collator
RUN /usr/local/bin/parachain-collator --version

EXPOSE 30333 9933 9944
VOLUME ["/adder-collator"]

#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/adder-collator"]  ... files not found
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/parachain-collator"]
```

In above Dockerfile, I removed `adder-collator` and `undying-collator` because they are not in the Substrate-Parachain-template repo. Do I need them?

My Zombienet network definition:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "gcr.io/p-network-202104/collator:t5"
  command = "parachain-collator"

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

I made an image from the above Dockerfile, then ran the same Zombienet tests as those in my previous posts. But the test failed for the same error: parachain block height is still zero

About ENTRYPOINT, what executable should I put there?

Should I use `parachain-collator` in ENTRYPOINT?

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/parachain-collator"]`

The code repo: https://github.com/AuroraLantean/-substrate-parachain-template0918

Comment: Hi @Russo, I can reproduce now and I working on a fix ( and a working example). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a new version of `zombienet` (v1.2.36) and created this demo repo [substrate-parachain-template-zombienet](https://github.com/pepoviola/substrate-parachain-template-zombienet) from the parachain-template and I added two dockerfile options (one injecting the binary and the other compiling and injecting into the final image).

Also, in this repo there is a simple `zombienet` test case with the network configuration using the image from this repo.

```
[settings]
enable_tracing = false

[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.22"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/pepoviola/substrate-parachain-template-zombienet:v0.0.0"
  command = "parachain-collator"
  args = ["-lparachain=debug"]
```

Tests works as expected using kubernetes provider.

```
-----------------------------------------


     Network launched 

         In namespace zombie-8f6d290a60ae265e022663c1cd09719d with kubernetes provider


         Node name: alice

         Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51063#/explorer

         Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:51068/metrics

---



         Node name: bob

         Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51143#/explorer

         Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:51148/metrics

---




     Parachain ID: 2000

     Parachain chainSpecPath path: /var/folders/rz/1cyx7hfj31qgb98d8_cg7jwh0000gn/T/zombie-8f6d290a60ae265e022663c1cd09719d_-62735-7Y6C8XAuiuLx/rococo-local-2000.json


         Node name: collator01

         Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51215#/explorer

         Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:51220/metrics

---

    ✔ alice: is up (1837ms)
    ✔ bob: is up (1786ms)
2022-05-27 13:44:58        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead, mmr_generateBatchProof, state_trieMigrationStatus
    ✔ alice: parachain 2000 is registered within 225 seconds (4742ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches glob "*rted #1*" within 10 seconds (1678ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches "Imported #[0-9]+" within 10 seconds (1662ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches "Imported new block." within 10 seconds (1620ms)
    ✔ alice: parachain 2000 block height is at least 6 within 250 seconds (138055ms)
    ✔ alice: reports node_roles is 4
    ✔ alice: reports sub_libp2p_is_major_syncing is 0

     Node's logs are available in /var/folders/rz/1cyx7hfj31qgb98d8_cg7jwh0000gn/T/zombie-8f6d290a60ae265e022663c1cd09719d_-62735-7Y6C8XAuiuLx/logs

     Deleting network


  9 passing (9m)
```

Can you use try the new version of zombienet and use this approach to build your image?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: wow thank you it works! May I know why you set enable_tracing = false? Do I need that?

Comment: Hi @Russo, at the moment is needed because `tracing` is enabled by default with `k8s` provider and the parachain-template node doesn't support the tracing flag. I will fix this in a new version of zombienet.

Comment: is there a reason why you and Polkadot team chose Ubuntu as base image? I think Debian is more secure than Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: could you help with Github CICD setup with Zombienet? Thanks https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/how-to-setup-kubectl-minikube-zombienet-tests-in-github-cicd

Answer (score 0):

The Docker base file:

```
#debian:10-slim
#FROM debian@sha256:6ef4731388c03b38e58ea77aef9396c216095e1843742fc7cf5038901cc1f081
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && apt install -y git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev procps vim make wget build-essential
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf >> install-rust.sh
RUN chmod u+x install-rust.sh
RUN ./install-rust.sh -y
RUN PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/env
SHELL ["bash", "-lc"]
RUN rustup update
RUN rustup update nightly
RUN rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly

CMD [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
# docker build -f zombienet/Dockerfile.base -t gcr.io/p-network-202104/rust:2004ubuntu220530 .
# docker push gcr.io/p-network-202104/rust:2004ubuntu220530
```

The correct Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/p-network-202104/rust:2004ubuntu220530 AS builder
ARG PROFILE=release

WORKDIR /builds/collator
COPY . /builds/collator

RUN cargo build --locked --${PROFILE}

# This image has to be the same as the base image for the builder above 
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04
#debian:10-slim
#FROM debian@sha256:6ef4731388c03b38e58ea77aef9396c216095e1843742fc7cf5038901cc1f081
#FROM debian:stretch-slim
#buster-slim

# show backtraces
ENV RUST_BACKTRACE 1

# install tools and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
  libssl1.1 \
  ca-certificates && \
  # apt cleanup
  apt-get autoremove -y && \
  apt-get clean && \
  find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f -not -name lock -delete; \
  # add user and link ~/.local/share/polkadot to /data
  useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /polkadot polkadot && \
  mkdir -p /data /polkadot/.local/share && \
  chown -R polkadot:polkadot /data && \
  ln -s /data /polkadot/.local/share/polkadot


COPY --from=builder /builds/collator/target/release/parachain-collator /usr/local/bin

USER polkadot

# check if executable works in this container
RUN /usr/local/bin/parachain-collator --version

EXPOSE 30333 9933 9944 9615
VOLUME ["/polkadot"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/parachain-collator"]
# docker build -f zombienet/Dockerfile -t gcr.io/p-network-202104/collator:v6 .
# docker push gcr.io/p-network-202104/collator:v6
```