# Parachain node frequently halted for and again start syncing

Tags: polkadot, parachain-collator

We setup polkadot parachain node for asset and node frequently halted for and again start syncing.

Dockr image - `parity/polkadot-parachain:latest` (docker hub)
here is the docker compose file

```
version: “3.7”
services:
node:
image: parity/polkadot-parachain:latest
restart: on-failure
ports:
- “9944:9944”
- “30333:30333”
- “2332:9933”
volumes:
- /localdir/parity:/parity
container_name: polkadot-parachain
mem_limit: 2g
command:
–prometheus-external
–chain=‘statemint’
–rpc-port 9933
–rpc-cors all
–rpc-external
–pruning
archive
```

Node logs

```sh
2023-09-06 18:05:46 Polkadot parachain ,
2023-09-06 18:05:46 :v: version 1.0.0-2306bfb7565 ,
2023-09-06 18:05:46 :heart: by Parity Technologies admin@parity.io, 2017-2023 ,
2023-09-06 18:05:46 :clipboard: Chain specification: Polkadot Asset Hub ,
2023-09-06 18:05:46 :label: Node name: bored-children-6550 ,
2023-09-06 18:05:46 :bust_in_silhouette: Role: FULL ,
2023-09-06 18:05:46 :floppy_disk: Database: RocksDb at /parity/.local/share/polkadot-parachain/chains/asset-hub-polkadot/db/full ,
2023-09-06 18:05:49 Parachain id: Id(1000) ,
2023-09-06 18:05:49 Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ ,
2023-09-06 18:05:49 Is collating: no ,
```

Thnaks
Umang Awasthy

Comment: Please provide logs that help us discover the problem.

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas, please check node logs section

Comment: Doesn't provide info that is useful

Answer (score 0):

As Daan said in the comments is hard for us to discover what is wrong with the logs you provided.

It looks that the polkadot-parachain starts correctly, but how are you running the  relay chain?
Here you can see how to use your docker images with Zombienet to run all your testing environment (Relay-chain + parachain): [Zombienet: Substrate-Parachain-Template ... How to write the Dockerfile?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/zombienet-substrate-parachain-template-how-to-write-the-dockerfile?rq=1)

I also recommend to check the basic tutorials in the Substrate docs: [Prepare a local relay chain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/) or how to use Zombienet to set up all your testing environment: [Set up a parachain test network](https://docs.substrate.io/test/set-up-a-test-network/). And finally you can check some examples of docker scripts in the [cumulus (parachain) repository](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/cumulus/docker/scripts).